# Previous/next post links displaying wrong category than is desired

Tags: categories, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I want my `single.php` to display posts in the same category for the previous and next posts underneath the post. The problem is that each of my posts belongs to multiple categories, and they are displayed through one of the other categories (24) versus the one I want them to display from (27). Does that even make sense?

Example Categories:

Characters (parent category)  (Subcategory IDs listed below:)

- 24 (This category ID displaying instead.)
- 27 (This is the category ID that I want to display.)

Now, my question is, how do I choose the category I want to be pulled from (27) instead of the one being automatically pulled (24)? Here is my code below (that I've found and been fiddling with), with what I've tried so far.

```
    <?php
    if (is_single() && in_category('stories')) {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $cat = get_the_category(); //I've tried changing this to my category (both ID and slug)
        $current_cat_id = $cat[0]->cat_ID;  //Also tried plugging ID and slug

        $args = array(
            'category' => $current_cat_id, //Also tried plugging ID and slug
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);

        $ids = array();
        foreach ($posts as $thepost) {
            $ids[] = $thepost->ID;
        }

        $thisindex = array_search($post_id, $ids);
        $previd = $ids[$thisindex - 1];
        $nextid = $ids[$thisindex + 1];

        if (!empty($nextid)) {
            ?><div class="double-grid"><a rel="next" href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextid) ?>"><div class="image-tile tile-on-archive-page" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($nextid); ?>'"> <div class="gold-button">LAST STORY >></div></div></a></div><?php
        }
        if (!empty($previd)) {
            ?><div class="double-grid"><a rel="prev" href="<?php echo get_permalink($previd) ?>"><div class="image-tile tile-on-archive-page" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($previd); ?>'"> <div class="gold-button">NEXT STORY >></div></div></a></div><?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It is not clear where are categories and subcategories.

Comment: How so? What more do you need to know about the categories?

Comment: So, `Stories` is a subcategory of `Characters`? Hmmm.

Comment: That is correct. "Characters" is the category, and "Stories" is the subcategory that I want to be displayed. However, another subcategory "John" is being displayed instead. I want to know how to tell the code to select "Stories" instead.

Comment: Especially since my posts are under multiple categories and subcategories.

Comment: Are you trying to get these links inside The Loop?

Comment: Indeed. I am inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazah! I thought I'd post it here, but I worked with someone on the development forums on Wordpress.org and they actually solved the problem for me.

You can see the solution and tweaks here:  [WordPress.org Forum Topic](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/previousnext-post-link-in-category-bizzare-outcome/#post-8853431)

Answer (score 0):

Your code problem is you get only the first category of a post because `$cat[0]` is the first, not current.

Inside The Loop:

```
<?php
previous_post_link( // prints the formatted link
    '<span>&laquo; %link</span>',  // beautifying around
    'Prev in this cat',            // the text (%link) to be used in the span above
    true,                          // confirm that you want only this category
    '',                            // no categories to exclude
    'category'                     // taxonomy name
);

echo " | "; // just a separator between next and prev

/* The same setup here, not shown to keep the answer clean */
next_post_link();
```

See [previous_post_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) for parameters.

If you are outside of The Loop, let me know, I'll update the answer and supply the additional code and comments.

Comment: I have tried this. The problem with this one is when I have multiple categories assigned to the post. Then it selects the first category ID that is assigned to the post--rather than the specific category I want.

Comment: On another note: I've tried excluding the categories that I don't want to show up (as shown on the Codex page you included), however, it doesn't seem to work. It still picks the category with the lowest ID that is on the post to navigate between. I need to be able to pick the one I want it to read.

Comment: Don't be nervous. I'll get it done because it's the interesting situation for me too. Just keep cool.

Comment: Print  the `echo $cat[0]->cat_ID;` on every page you are dreaming. What it say?

Comment: It prints the number 24 when I inspect the page. (Which is the ID for my "John" category, rather than the 27 of my "Stories" category.)

Comment: So, 24 is the Category ID to be in? You can finally edit your question to be more specific. And you use ID not slug or name.

Comment: See edits. Does this work?

Comment: Are you playing on the localhost or the live one?

Comment: I'm on my local.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem until you give more info where your posts are under which directory (-ies) or subdirectory (-ies), ordered by unknown something.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear about what type of information you are looking for. (Forgive me.) Directories where my posts are? Do you mean the backend structure? Or what my taxonomy structure is like?